# Repeating rows leaving a blank row

Tags: xml

I've got a section set up in my form to add Permits to WorkOrder Packets. Each packet can have multiple Permits added to it. Currently I can add permits to this and the functionality works as desired but there is a blank permit record with no header or any data attached to it at the very top of where my new permits go when they get added and it just sits there. Each permit can be edit/deleted and those buttons on the ghost permit are interfereing with my actual permits because when I mouse over the edit button on my actual permit it will highlight the button on my "ghost" permit as well.

I feel like i'm just off by a tag or something but have tried nearly everything under the sun and cannot seem to figure out where I'm going wrong to eliminate this "ghost" blank permit.

```
               <h3 id="PermitHeader">Permitting</h3>
                    <div>                                                   
                       <div class="container">
                            <div class="containerSec">
                                <input type="hidden" name="PermitId" id="PermitId" class="woPermit woPreCon woConst woRestoration PermitId" />
                                <label class="lblPermitEntry"><u>New Permit Entry:</u></label>
                                <label class="ter" id="lblPermitEntity" for="PermitEntity">Entity:
                                    <br />
                                    <input type="text" name="PermitEntity" id="PermitEntity" class="woPermit woPreCon woConst woRestoration permitEntry" size="11" maxlength="11">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="Permit/Temporary/TempPermitEntity" />
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                    </input>
                                </label>
                                <label class="ter" id="lblPermitType" for="PermitType">Permit Type:
                                    <br />
                                    <select name="PermitType" id="PermitType" class="woPreCon">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="Permit/Temporary/TempPermitType" />
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="document('xcel_lookups.xml')/lookups/permitType/row">
                                            <option>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="value" /></xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="value" />
                                            </option>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </select>
                                </label>
                                <label class="ter" id="lblPermitDateSubmitted" for="PermitDateSubmitted">Date Submitted:
                                    <br />
                                    <input type="text" name="PermitDateSubmitted" id="PermitDateSubmitted" class="datePicker woPermit woPreCon woConst woRestoration permitEntry" size="11" maxlength="10">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="Permit/Temporary/TempPermitDateSubmitted" />
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                    </input>
                                </label>
                                <label class="ter" id="lblPermitDateReceived" for="PermitDateReceived">Date Received:
                                    <br />
                                    <input type="text" name="PermitDateReceived" id="PermitDateReceived" class="datePicker woPermit woPreCon woConst woRestoration permitEntry" size="11" maxlength="10">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="Permit/Temporary/TempPermitDateReceived" />
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                    </input>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="containerSec" style="float: right;">
                                <input type="button" value="Add" id="permitAdd" repeat="repeatPermit" />
                                <input type="button" value="Update" id="permitUpdate" class="hidden" />
                                <input type="button" value="Clear" id="permitClear" class="woPermit woConst woRestoration woPreCon" />
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                        <div>
                            <xsl:for-each select="Permit/Records/Record">
                                <xsl:variable name="permitCount" select="position()" />
                                <div repeat="repeatPermit" class="permitRecord">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="delete">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('deletePermit', $permitCount)" />
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('permitEntity', $permitCount)" />
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="PermitId=''">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                                                permitRecord hidden
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:when>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                    <div class="permitHeader">
                                        <b><span class="permitSpan">
                                            <xsl:choose>
                                                <xsl:when test="PermitId!=''">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Permit ', $permitCount - 1)" />
                                                </xsl:when>
                                            </xsl:choose>
                                        </span></b>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="permittingId" class="woPreCon woPermit permittingId">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="concat('permittingId', $permitCount)" />
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="PermitId" />
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                        </input>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="containerSet">
                                            <label class="ter">Entity:
                                                <br />
                                                <input type="hidden" class="woPermit woPreCon woConst woRestoration permitEntity" size="11" maxlength="11">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="PermEntity" />
                                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('permitEntity', $permitCount)" />
                                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                                </input>
                                                <span class="permitEntity empty">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="PermEntity" />
                                                </span>
                                            </label>
                                            <label class="ter">Permit Type:
                                                <br />
                                                <input type="hidden" class="woPermit woPreCon woConst woRestoration permitType" size="11" maxlength="11">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="PermType" />
                                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('permitType', $permitCount)" />
                                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                                </input>
                                                <span class="permitType empty">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="PermType" />
                                                </span>
                                            </label>
                                            <label class="ter">Date Submitted:
                                                <br />
                                                <input type="hidden" class="woPermit woPreCon woConst woRestoration permitDateSubmitted" size="11" maxlength="11">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="PermDateSubmitted" />
                                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('permitDateSubmitted', $permitCount)" />
                                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                                </input>
                                                <span class="permitDateSubmitted empty">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="PermDateSubmitted" />
                                                </span>
                                            </label>
                                            <label class="ter">Date Received:
                                                <br />
                                                <input type="hidden" class="woPermit woPreCon woConst woRestoration permitDateReceived" size="11" maxLength="11">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="PermDateReceived" />
                                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('permitDateReceived', $permitCount)" />
                                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                                </input>
                                                <span class="permitDateReceived empty">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="PermDateReceived" />
                                                </span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="containerSec" style="float: right;">
                                            <input type="button" value="Edit" class="woPermit woPreCon woConst woRestoration permitEdit" />
                                            <input type="button" value="Delete" class="woPermit woPreCon woConst woRestoration permitDelete">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('deletePermit', $permitCount)" />
                                                </xsl:attribute>
                                            </input>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </div>                          
                        <div class="container">
                            <label id="lblPermitNotes" for="PermitNotes">Permit Notes: <br />
                                <textarea id="PermitNotes" class="notes woPreCon woConst woRestoration woPermit">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Permit/Notes"/>
                                </textarea>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```